# textview.settext does not obey fontFamily

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts

I have defined my textview as:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Eicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
        android:fontFamily="@font/weathericons"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="@string/sunset"
        android:textColor="#3f51b5"
        android:textSize="25sp">
    </TextView>
```

which is rendered properly in android-studio, and in the main app, unless  I change the `android:text` with textview.settext as:

```
   textViewEicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Eicon);
   holder.textViewEicon.setText("&#xf052");
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

@font only works on android studio 3.0 upwards using gradle 3.0 upwards also